# Atmospheric scale height

Tags: astrophysics, atmospheric-science

In researching atmospheric scale heights I have found that Earth’s atmospheric scale height quoted as both 8.5km and 0.000139m-1.

I understand the significance of 8.5km and the natural log but I am unsure as to why it is also quoted as 0.000139m-1?

Comment: Perhaps you can post the source?
For an isothermal atmosphere, the pressure goes as $P(h)=P_0 e^{-h/H}$, so the second form is useful for someone who likes to multiply, namely $H^{-1} h$. The only problem I see here is that $1/(8.5km) = 0.00011765 m^{-1}$, which is why I would like to see the source.

Comment: Hello Damian, this FAA document quotes 0.000139m-1. https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/media/iii.4.1.7_returning_from_space.pdf

Comment: Thanks. And the $8.5 km$?
If you include a document, please also include page number.